# alembic revision - multiple heads (due branching) error

Tags: python, git, alembic

I've got an application and I wanted to create a new migration for it today. When I run

```
$ alembic revision -m "__name__"
```

I got a message

```
Only a single head is supported. The script directory has multiple heads (due branching), which must be resolved by manually editing the revision files to form a linear sequence. 
Run `alembic branches` to see the divergence(s).
```

Running

```
alembic branches
```

gives nothing

I'm new to alembic. There are 2 developers working on this app and we have 2 git branches - master & develop (I'm not sure if this have anything to do with it).

Any clue on what is this about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run

```
$ python manage.py db history
```

And as a result I got

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ python manage.py db history

Rev: 29c319804087 (head)
Parent: 313837798149
Path: migrations/versions/29c319804087_.py

    empty message

    Revision ID: 29c319804087
    Revises: 313837798149
    Create Date: 2014-03-05 21:26:32.538027

Rev: 313837798149
Parent: 280061454d2a
Path: migrations/versions/313837798149_.py

    empty message

    Revision ID: 313837798149
    Revises: 280061454d2a
    Create Date: 2014-01-10 03:19:39.838932

Rev: 280061454d2a
Parent: None
Path: migrations/versions/280061454d2a_.py

    empty message

    Revision ID: 280061454d2a
    Revises: None
    Create Date: 2013-12-08 03:04:55.885033


Rev: 2e74f61d3b80 (head)
Parent: 49501407aec9
Path: migrations/versions/2e74f61d3b80_o2_lease.py

    o2 lease

    Revision ID: 2e74f61d3b80
    Revises: 49501407aec9
    Create Date: 2014-02-28 10:38:06.187420

Rev: 49501407aec9
Parent: None
Path: migrations/versions/49501407aec9_.py

    empty message

    Revision ID: 49501407aec9
    Revises: None
    Create Date: 2014-01-22 11:27:08.002187
```

What you can see here is 2 different branches. One starts from 49501407aec9 and second from 280061454d2a. I moved 49501407aec9 and the following 2e74f61d3b80 out of the /versions directory, run

```
$ python manage.py db revision
```

and it created a new migration file.

Comment: This is the worst possible course of action. Please refer to the [highest-voted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456404/918959) answer instead.

Answer (score 81):

Perhaps the most conventional (and robust) solution is to use `alembic merge heads`. In the same way that when you have two branches in Git you can bring them back together with a merge commit, in Alembic when you have two branches you can bring them back together with a merge revision.

For instance, suppose we have a revision 1a6b1a4a0574 that adds table A, and a revision 2e49118db057 that adds table B. We can see these revisions (both marked as `(head)`) in `alembic history`:

```
$ alembic history
<base> -> 2e49118db057 (head), Add table B
<base> -> 1a6b1a4a0574 (head), Add table A
```

Then we can merge them by running `alembic merge heads`:

```
$ alembic merge heads
  Generating /Users/markamery/alembictest/alembic/versions/409782f4c459_.py ... done
$ alembic history
2e49118db057, 1a6b1a4a0574 -> 409782f4c459 (head) (mergepoint), empty message
<base> -> 2e49118db057, Add table B
<base> -> 1a6b1a4a0574, Add table A
```

If one of your revisions may have already been run somewhere (including on the development machine of one of your coworkers), then you probably want to use `alembic merge` instead of tinkering with the `down_revision` of one of the revisions, as the other answers here suggest. The danger of tinkering with the down revision is that it may result in a revision never getting applied. For instance, suppose that your colleague Bob has already pulled down your branch with revision 2e49118db057 and run `alembic upgrade head`, creating table B. Then you decide to modify the `down_revision` of 2e49118db057 to point to 1a6b1a4a0574, which Bob has never seen or run before. Bob pulls down your change, runs `alembic upgrade head`, and... nothing happens, because as far as Alembic is concerned he's already at the `head` and doesn't need to run 1a6b1a4a0574. And so Bob ends up never getting table A and probably never figures out why his database is in a broken state.

Don't break Bob's database - make a merge revision instead.

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to fix version conflicts in alembic.

Comment: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/script.html#alembic.script.ScriptDirectory.get_current_head fails after merge because head will contain two revisions.Would you know how to work around that?

Comment: @Brayoni yes - you run `alembic merge heads`. That's literally what this entire answer is about.

Answer (score 38):

This issue happens when two alembic migrations are branched from the same migration. Usually, this happens when multiple people are making schema changes. To fix it you just have to adjust the`down_revision` of your migration to be that of the latest one. Running `alembic history` shows us this:

```
2f4682466279 -> f34e92e9dc54 (head), Fifth revision (on a separate branch)
2f4682466279 -> f673ac37b34a (head), Fifth revision (local)
2dc9337c3987 -> 2f4682466279, Fourth revision
0fa2aed0866a -> 2dc9337c3987, Third revision
22af4a75cf06 -> 0fa2aed0866a, Second revision
9a8942e953eb -> 22af4a75cf06, First revision
```

You can see that one of the Fifth revisions was made locally and it's downstream revision is`2f4682466279` but whoever made the other Fifth revision got the same downstream revision too.

Go into one of the Fifth revision files and update `down_revision` variable to reference the other Fifth revision, like this:

```
f673ac37b34a -> f34e92e9dc54 (head), Fifth revision (on a separate branch)
2f4682466279 -> f673ac37b34a, Fifth revision (local)
2dc9337c3987 -> 2f4682466279, Fourth revision
0fa2aed0866a -> 2dc9337c3987, Third revision
22af4a75cf06 -> 0fa2aed0866a, Second revision
9a8942e953eb -> 22af4a75cf06, First revision
```

In this case I updated migration `f34e92e9dc54` to have `down_revision='f673ac37b34a'`.

Comment: Be careful with this approach. It may occasionally be the right thing to do if you want to keep your revision history tidy *and* you know that none of your multiple heads have yet been run anywhere... but if you *don't* have that guarantee, you risk breaking one of your databases by causing it to skip a migration. See the end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456404/1709587) for a description of how this approach can go wrong. Using `alembic merge heads` - while perhaps *uglier*, due to creating an extra revision - is a more robust approach.

Comment: I realised we were doing this for the past couple years. It is non scalable when there are more devs on the team. We should have done `merge heads` and we only realised now.

Comment: This is really not the way you should go.  Use merge heads like Mark Amery suggests below or you will break your coworkers' databases.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `merge` command.

An Alembic merge is a migration file that joins two or more "head" files together. If the two branches we have right now can be said to be a "tree" structure, introducing this merge file will turn it into a "diamond" structure:

```
                              -- ae1027a6acf -->
                           /                   \
<base> --> 1975ea83b712 -->                      --> mergepoint
                           \                   /
                            -- 27c6a30d7c24 -->
```

Hence;

```
$ alembic merge -m "merge ae1 and 27c" ae1027 27c6a
  Generating /path/to/foo/versions/53fffde5ad5_merge_ae1_and_27c.py ... done
```

If you prefer using `command`:

```
>>> from alembic.config import Config
>>> from alembic import command
>>> alembic_cfg = Config("path to alembic.ini")
>>> command.merge(alembic_cfg, revisions=["27c6a30d7c24", "ae1027a6acf"], message="Merge 27c6a30d7c24 and ae1027a6acf")
```

**Reference**

- [Working with Branches](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/branches.html#working-with-branches)
- [See section on resolving without merge](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/resolving-database-schema-conflicts)